# Django add a many to one field to user object

Tags: django, django-models

I'm creating a `Network` class that has a many-to-one relationship with the Django `User` class. In other words, a `Network` can have many `User` and each `User` has only one `Network`. It's easy to add many-to-many relationships because I can add the many-to-many field in the `Network` class; however, it's hard to apply many-to-one relationship since I need to add the the foreign key in `User` class. There is no way I can do that.

I do have a `UserProfile` class that has a one-to-one relationship with `User`, but it's only for storing additional information about the `User`, not any relationships. All my other relationships defined are relating to `User`, not `UserProfile`.

Is there a way to create a many-to-one relationship to the `User` and `Network` class without using the `UserProfile`? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only things I can think of are subclassing `User`, which is tricky because the admin has no way to turn a base object (`User` in this case) into a subclassed object (`NetworkUser`, and yes I've tried), or creating a `NetworkUser` model with a `OneToOne` relationship to `User` and a `ForeignKey` to `Network`.  I'd recommend the latter, because while you feel sure now that you just want to add one thing to `User` and it shouldn't be a big deal, later on there will be more to add.

The thing that bothers me about directly messing with `User` is that this is only for a single app, not necessarily the whole project, and modifying `User` in a way that will affect other apps in the project.